# The take lemma needs a coinductive proof

Tags: category-theory, induction, proof-theory, coalgebras, theorem-provers

In [Are coinductive proofs necessary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220827/are-coinductive-proofs-necessary), the answerer claimed that we cannot prove inductively the take lemma:

> Two streams that agree on all initial subsequences of given length are the same.

I was wondering how do you prove that this is the case.

Comment: It seems to me that to prove this metatheorem, you need to carefully define "inductive proof"... certainly this can't just mean "any proof that involves induction at some point", since you could take any proof and tack on a trivial induction. Maybe it would be easier to define "coinductive proof" and rule it out. If streams are *defined* coinductively, then it's not clear how to prove anything nontrivial about streams without coinduction!

Comment: here is an example proof https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp12/papers/opebtp/opebtp.pdf (page 267) and related references

Comment: in retrospect, this might be more relevant http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/corecursive.pdf